# Compile html from templates on nodejs

Tags: node.js, template-engine

My issue here is that I want to compile html templates on nodejs server. We want to make dynamic templates, where we can compile templates + insert data into templates using JSON object.

I tried using node's package "Mustache", and I am getting what I mentioned above. But the issue with Mustache is that the html is written in script tag in *.html file. To compile I have to read it as a file stream into a variable and use it. And I don't want to do that as I previously had issues with fs.

So my question is that what other node's module can I use where I can design complete HTML templates and then compile them using the data from JSON objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out hogan-express. It's basically moustach(javascript version) which is better than the default `hjs` module that express installs on start.

You can send data to the template using variables `{{variableName}}`

This variable is set on your backend with the following(I'm assuming you are using express)

```
var value = "dynamicValue";

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html', {
        variableName: value
    });
});
```

In your template you simply call {{ variableName }}

Note, this needs to be in you app.js

```
app.engine('html', require('hogan-express'));
```

As for other options you can use jade, ejs, etc... I personally prefer hogan

Comment: This is a very viable option. The only issue that I see is that in documentation it is mentioned that it is developed for express 3.x. I am developing on express 4.x, and can't test it till morning, so wanted to ask if anyone has tried it with express 4.x?